# Laravel Form Builder String with '@' being transformed into a code

Tags: php, laravel, formbuilder

I am having a problem with values with '@' signs in laravel form select. It seems that all string that has '@' is being transformed into code. But this only happens on the server (which a centOS server). but works properly on my local machine.

The picture below is how is should be and is working on my local.

[image]

Then this is how it is in CentOS server

[image]

How can I fixed this? Is it in the setup of the server or I need to have a catch for this? I've tried to put an htmlentities for their values but still works like that. Not really sure what is causing it to not work in centOS. Thanks for your replies.

This is how the json object was formulated in a config file.

```
   'group'=>[
            'type'=>'choice',
            'optional'=>[
                'label' => 'Group',
                'choices'=>function(){
                    return Modules\Group\Entities\Group::all()->lists('name','id')->toArray();
                },
                // 'multiple' => true,
                'attr' => ['multiple' => 'multiple', 'class' =>'multiselect-checkbox']
            ]
        ],
```

And this is the view on how they are rendered. It is a php file not a blade file.

```
<?= Form::select($name, (array)$emptyVal + $options['choices'], $options['selected'], $options['attr']) ?>
```

Comment: Simply do `{{ '@' }}`. That's it. It will be treated as a string literal.

Comment: How're you rendering your form fields in your view?

Comment: the value is coming from a database. How can I escape that ?

Comment: why you are using <?= tags in you blade? just use {{ }} it should work, if that is the case let me know

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ yes it did, it works quite fine actually.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ actually I am not using blade on that. It is just a php file. I tried changing it to blade but I was getting an error of not being able to include a file which is needed.

Comment: Laravel parsing the view, including braces, maybe you have name conventions problem, that wont change the fact that it is being parsed through Laravel.

Comment: you could also do some thing like this $output = htmlspecialchars("DogsLovers@SG", ENT_QUOTES); but that is servered for you in laravel by using braces.

Comment: Btw blade is php file, the reason er call it blade that it is supped by laravel framework, so you are using blade, you are just not aware of it

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ I tried converting it to blade and removed the include that was causing the problem but once I check the form view. It only prints the select HTML.

Comment: Filename.blade.php is how to name it and from controller just use filename the rest is severed for you, you might give blade a look

Comment: yes that's what I did. for the {{}} to work. It is not working in filename.php files.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ I am currently using 5.1.6 version.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ are you referring to the hierarchy of my files ? Thanks so much for you help.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ ok I will attach an image of the hierarchy of the resources

Comment: ok, just remove the image for now to not make a noise to the question, if your system has worked fine with .php extension so far continue with it, but when you have time you need to find out why it is not work if you change file blade.php it should work out of the box, there must some thing you have done here or there. but as said before {{ }} normally wont work in php, so if works in your case that is a good sign of that laravel is parsing the file. I think we should close this question for now, and if you find more trouble with the blade naming ask a new question so we can help you.

Comment: shortly the structure is ok, you could eventually pack the project as zip and share it with me I can look at possible places where it be done wrong, but that said you need to ask a new question and make me aware of it because this question in my opinion is solved.

Comment: you are welcome please check it as answered and vote up if you like, for now and keep me updated if you need support with debugging it.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ ok. Thanks again.

Comment: you are welcome keep it up and update me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong tag `<?= ?>` in blade use braces in stead `{!! !!}` or `{{ }}` all depends on your strategy, I suggest you to look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#displaying-data).

Your code should be like this:

```
{!! Form::select($name, (array)$emptyVal + $options['choices'],
                       $options['selected'], $options['attr']) !!}
```

> By default, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through
>   PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks.

Please check [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#displaying-data).

Thx to @Jonathon aware me for `{!! !!}` I was to fast on the keys.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `{!! !!}` syntax? You wouldn't want to run `htmlentities` on some HTML code or it would encode the `<`, `>` characters etc. I know what you've put does work though, not sure why but i'm pretty sure it should be `{!! !!}`

Comment: @Jonathon btw the problem was that his CentOS for some reason compiled the @ sign as code, so at the same time he had some problems with his blade, I have promised to look at laters, but regardless I will add your update aswell

Comment: Yeah I would agree :)

Comment: @Jonathon coolbeans, thx bro, some times it goes very fast with things ;)